# ExtJS: consolidating records in store

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Considering a simple example, consider the following store of records:

```
{ item: 'A', group: 'red', quantity: 1 }, 
{ item: 'A', group: 'green', quantity: 1 }, 
{ item: 'B', group: 'red', quantity: 1 }, 
{ item: 'B', group: 'blue', quantity: 1 },
{ item: 'C', group: 'green', quantity: 1 }
```

My goal is to have a grid with each distinct `group` field as a filter, where all active filters consolidate `quantity`'s into the unique `item`'s. Examples:

```
// show: red, green          // show: green           // show: red, blue
item | quantity              item | quantity          item | quantity
---------------              ---------------          ---------------
 A   |   2                     A  |   1                 A  |   1
 B   |   1                     C  |   1                 B  |   2
 C   |   1
```

Is there a built-in way to handle this? My ideas were:

1. First apply filer on `group`. Then use `collect` to get all unique `item`'s remaining as a basis for the rows. Do a `find` for each of these items and sum the quantities of the results.
2. Rethink my models to something like:

.

```
{ 
    item: 'A', quantities: [
        { group: 'red', quantity: 1 }, { group: 'green', quantity: 2 }
    ]
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS grid has a grouping view out of the box that might be a good fit for what you are doing.

The setup from the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping) is like this:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'employeeStore',
    fields:['name', 'seniority', 'department'],
    groupField: 'department',
    data: {'employees':[
        { "name": "Michael Scott",  "seniority": 7, "department": "Management" },
        { "name": "Dwight Schrute", "seniority": 2, "department": "Sales" },
        { "name": "Jim Halpert",    "seniority": 3, "department": "Sales" },
        { "name": "Kevin Malone",   "seniority": 4, "department": "Accounting" },
        { "name": "Angela Martin",  "seniority": 5, "department": "Accounting" }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'employees'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Employees',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',     dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Seniority', dataIndex: 'seniority' }
    ],
```

> ```
>    features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
> ```

```
    width: 200,
    height: 275,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

In general look through the Examples on Sencha's web page it will give you lots of useful ideas on how to design your components and the code behind them.

Comment: You've been a great help tonight. That being said - I've seen these docs - but I was hoping there may be a way to do the grouping where the end 'groups' consolidate to become the row primitives. Closer to only displaying the summeries here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/grid/group-summary-grid.html

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. If the out of box grouping is not fitting, then you could do one of two things. A) Create 3 filters to extract the data based on functions (see grid docs for filters), and add 3 buttons to toolbar that trigger your filters.  B) Use grid filters user extension. This adds menu items to the columns. Look at this example under the Size column: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Comment: Ah yes I've seen these. Still - the filtering/grouping of columns isn't the bottleneck; it's taking the **results** of these filters/groups, and mapping all the records in a single group/filter result into a *single* row who's column entries are dependent on all the contributing records

Comment: Probably a better fit for a server side function.

Comment: Ya - that's pretty much what I was thinking was going to be necesary. Thanks for your help though